# Flip a tree structure using css

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a code that creates a tree structure of data. and it is as below.

```css
ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  width: 0;
  height: 2em;
}

#theAccount {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 325px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #f4f6f9;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff9e3;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em .5em 0 .5em;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2em;
}

li:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

li:only-child:after,
li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

li:first-child::before,
li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div>

    <div id="theAccount">

      <h1>
        Main
      </h1>

    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Sub1 Tyesxt </li>
      <li>
        Sub 2 Tyesxt

      </li>
      <li>
        Sub3 Tyesxt

      </li>
      <li>
        Sub4 Tyesxt
      </li>
      <li>
        Sub5 Tyesxt

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the tree output that we get is top to bottom, I want to know how I can rotate it by 90 degrees. i.e. I want the tree to be from left to right like below with proper styling.

```
           |--Sub1 Tyesxt 
           |--Sub2 Tyesxt
Main ------|--Sub3 Tyesxt
           |--Sub4 Tyesxt
           |--Sub5 Tyesxt
```

Please let me know how Can I get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for `rotate()` function.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate())

> The rotate() CSS function defines a transformation that rotates an
> element around a fixed point on the 2D plane, without deforming it.
> Its result is a  data type.

An example:

```css
ul::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    width: 0;
    height: 2em;
  }

  #theAccount {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 325px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #f4f6f9;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff9e3;
  }

  ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2em 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2em .5em 0 .5em;
  }

  li:before,
  li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
  }

  li:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
  }

  li:only-child:after,
  li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
  }

  li:only-child {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  li:first-child::before,
  li:last-child::after {
    border: 0 none;
  }

  li:last-child::before {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  }

  li:first-child::after {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  }

.foo {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-top: 150px;
}

h1 {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

span {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: block;
    margin: 38px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

    <div class="foo">

      <div id="theAccount">

        <h1>
          Main
        </h1>

      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Sub1 Tyesxt</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Sub 2 Tyesxt</span>

        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Sub3 Tyesxt</span>

        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Sub4 Tyesxt</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Sub5 Tyesxt</span>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try with flex & grid, then border and list-style:

```css
body > div > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#theAccount {
  display: flex;
}
#theAccount:after {
  content: "";
  width: 7.5vw;/* whatever*/
  border: solid 1px ;
  margin: auto 0;
}
h1 {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0.15em 0.25em;
  background: ivory;
}
ul {
  border-left: solid 3px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
li {
  list-style: "\23e4\23e4\2800";
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
li:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -0.55em;
}
li:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: -0.45em;
}
li:first-of-type,
li:last-of-type {
  list-style: "\2800\23e4\2800\20 ";
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="theAccount">
      <h1>Main</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Sub1 Tyesxt </li>
      <li>Sub2 Tyesxt</li>
      <li>Sub3 Tyesxt</li>
      <li>Sub4 Tyesxt</li>
      <li>Sub5 Tyesxt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```